# Determine what cycle image was pressed in Windows Phone 8 application

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am wondering if it is possible to find what image was displayed to the user when they pressed the live tile to launch the application.  I know how to tell what live tile was pressed, just not what image was displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not. You should pin multiple tiles if you want a selective behaviour.